# run salesforce unit tests from soap api

Tags: api, soap-api, metadata-api

We are trying to run unit tests for [My Namespace] from Jenkins. We are writing Java JUnit tests. We would like to know how we can invoke unit test from SOAP api.

There is a reference to run unit tests here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_unit_tests_running.htm

And I ended up here to runTests() - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_calls_runtests.htm

But I don't know what is apexBinding variable in the example.

How can I trigger unit tests from Jenkins using Java? Does salesforce expose such functionality through an API?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few APIs that you can use. The two basic modes that I would consider for a Jenkins set up would be the Ant Migration Tool or SFDX.

## TestLevel

The TestLevel parameter (in the following examples) may be RunSpecifiedTests, RunLocalTests, or RunAllTestsInOrg (includes managed code).

## Ant Migration Tool

Set a target in ant that looks like this.

```
<target name="runAllTests">
  <sf:deploy username="${username}" password="${password}"
      serverurl="${serverurl}" deployroot="${root}"
      checkonly="true" testLevel="RunAllTestsInOrg" />
</target>
```

You can look at the documentation for [deploy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy.htm) for more options.

## SFDX CLI

The Salesforce DX CLI includes commands to run tests in several different ways.

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run [-u usernameOrAlias]
   [-s TestSuites | -n ClassNames | -t TestMethods | -l TestLevel ]
```

You can look at the documentation for [force:apex:test:run](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm) for more details.

## API

You can use the API in Java, .Net, C++, PHP and others that support WSDLs. You can use this as a last resort, but to simply get up and running, I'd suggest you use an already-built tool if you can. The `apexBinding` is the WSDL for executing Apex Code, which you can download from the Setup screen under Develop > API.